# Login Failed to connect to my cluster from mongo Shell .

Tags: mongodb

I tried almost everything. Changed my username and password form time to time and provided several roles to the user. But still I am stuck.

I think I am doing a minor mistake. [the prompt pic :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACwql.png)

Comment: Is user hariom present in test database?

Comment: Ya. Btw thanks for the response. I just noticed the error. It was the ip address. I was putting the wrong ip. But now it works.